# combine reducers for react hooks and context with type-safe

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

So I'm trying to use react hooks and context api to achieve "redux" like provider. After reading many mediums post and research on stackoverflow. I was able to get it to work however my problem is with the way to combine all of the reducer to achieve "single source of truth" and I would like to apply type-safe into it. I found this function on stackoverflow that can combine multiple reducer into one so I can use only 1 useReducer in my ContextProvider:

```
const combineReducers = (reducers) => {
    return (state, action) => {
        const tempState = { ...state };
        Object.keys(reducers).forEach((key) => {
            tempState[key] = reducers[key](tempState[key], action);
        });
        return tempState;
    };
};
```

To use the code above you just pass in an object of reducers for the reducers argument like so:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    combineReducers({
        reducerA: ReducerA,
        reducerB: ReducerB,
    }),
    INIT_STATE
);
```

however this doesn't have seperation of concern (at least that's what I understand) like if you take a look at this:

```
const mainReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: AppMenuActions | AuthActions | LayoutActions) => ({
    appMenu: AppMenuReducer(state.appMenu, action),
    auth: AuthReducer(state.auth, action),
    layout: LayoutReducer(state.layout, action),
});
```

This is good because now it each reducer only get pass it only the state that it manages. But I'm getting a type error with action because the action that got pass into mainReducer is discriminated unions and the action for each of the reducer take in is only that reducer actions. So now if I want this to work I would then need to use discriminated unions of all the actions of all of my reducers into each reducer function. This defeat the purpose of seperation of concerns.

You can view the whole code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/context-hooks-typescript-weh23?file=/src/context.tsx

the questions I have are:

1. if you take a look at my code over at codeandbox you will see that the [state, dispatch] we destructure from useReduce has type of any however when i pass that down to the context provider value it then become correct type my guess is that it is because of this?:

```
type AppContextType = {
    state: InitialStateType;
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<AppMenuActions | AuthActions | LayoutActions>;
};
```

how do I make it so that [state, dispatch] got the correct type?

2. the type AppContextType above how do I improve it because if you can see the dispatch type i'm using discriminated unions it is fine when I have 3 reducer actions now but if this increase it gonna get out of hand.

3. For the mainReducer function I can fix the code to work by making the action of all my reducer take a discriminated unions of all the actions this is fine but if I have many more reducers this would surely get out of hand. How do I make it so that the action infer the type based on the reducer that get pass in.


I have tried to convert the conbineReducers function to be type-safe like this but it is not fully. I struggling as i'm very new and my knowledge is limited:

```
const combineReducers = <S, A>(reducers: Array<Reducer<S, A>>) => {
    return (state: S, action: A) => {
        const tempState = { ...state };
        Object.keys(reducers).forEach((key) => {
            tempState[key] = reducers[key](tempState[key], action);
        });
        return tempState;
    };
};
```

I'm getting error on this line and I have no idea how to fix it or where to research:

```
tempState[key] = reducers[key](tempState[key], action);
```

Thank you if you have read it this far and those who willing to take their times and help me. Thank you very much!
sources: https://medium.com/hackernoon/finally-the-typescript-redux-hooks-events-blog-you-were-looking-for-c4663d823b01

Comment: What error do you get. The approach you have taken seems correct and would work

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm not getting any critical error although I was wondering how can I refactor it in such a way that down the road if I have more reducers it will be better for me if you just take a look at the AppContextType how actions being pass into dispatch generics type, if I have more reducers this will grow out of hand. read question 3 and the problem with the mainReducer fucntion. Thank you!

Comment: @MightAsWell Would be interested to know if you managed to refactor this further or find any help with a resource that helped improve this code? I'm learning React, tried Redux which I felt was overly complicated and now trying to achieve similar things with Context API and trying to achieve the same as you here :) Thanks

Comment: @user1259167 I know it kinda late but this was way back when I was learning React turned out im not more interested in backend development so kinda gave up on it a long time ago :D but I hoped you found what you were looking for. If you did please share here to help others as well.